# TiKz remove intersection between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a diagram however the overlap present is bothering me. How do I remove it so that the two circles seamlessly intersect.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick] (-0.5, 0) circle (1);
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick]  ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even if hand-drawn, it would be useful to have a picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is not clear, what you after. That borders of both circles are visible as is shown in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a result similar to [Thruston's answer,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660949/38080) in Ti*k*Z, what you can do is change [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/660938/edit) and first stroke the two circles and then fill the interiors, coloring over the crossing segments. I have also added a bit of TeX macros to avoid repeating the path.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\twocircles{%
        % notice that the "circle(1)" syntax is deprecated
        (-0.5, 0) circle[radius=1] ( 0.5, 0) circle[radius=1]%
    }
    \draw[orange!80, thick] \twocircles;
    \fill[yellow!30] \twocircles;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the border width is halved in this solution because the second `fill` instruction also wipes half of it.

Answer (score 2):

- Your question is not entirely clear what you after.
- I guess, that you may looking for ther following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow!30]
        (-0.5, 0) circle (1)
        ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\draw[orange!80, thick] 
        (-0.5, 0) circle (1)
        ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
As suggest @Qrrbrbirlbel in his comment (thank you very much for the tip), for proposed solution is no need for two separate paths:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick, radius=1] 
                      (-0.5, 0) circle[] (0.5, 0) circle[];
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before!

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but still looks good, I have incorporated it. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, nice suggestion! It works fine! CaN I incorporate it in my answer?

Comment: @Jackwannsee, well, (**i**) if answer not solve what you after, than please clarify (with some sketch) what you like to obtain;  (**ii**) , if you incorporate my proposition in your document, than it will be fer to accept my answer first (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the boundary as two arcs and fill the interior:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, orange!80, fill=yellow!30] (45:1) arc (45:315:1) arc (-135:135:1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "seamlessly", but I interpret this as you not wanting the border and making the circles a bit transparent.

I have attached the code below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, draw=orange!25, opacity=0.9] (-0.5, 0) circle (1);
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, draw=orange!25, opacity=0.9]  ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output will be:
[image: Circles]

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps like this?

[image]

I have done this in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile this with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path a, b, c;
    a = fullcircle scaled 200 shifted 60 left;
    b = fullcircle scaled 200 rotated 180 shifted 60 right;
    c = buildcycle(a, b); 

    color orange, yellow;
    orange = (1, 0.546, 0);
    yellow = (1, 1, 0.7);

    fill c withcolor yellow;
    draw c withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor orange;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

I have used the handy `buildcycle` macro to join the two circles into a single closed path.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is used to show that the new version is the sames size and shape as the original.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{acos(0.5)}% yes, it will be 60 degrees

\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick] (0, {sin(\angle)})
  arc[start angle={\angle}, end angle={360-\angle}, radius=1]
  arc[start angle={-180+\angle}, end angle={180-\angle}, radius=1]
  -- cycle;
  
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.5]% overlay original
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick] (-0.5, 0) circle (1);
\draw[color=orange!80, fill=yellow!30, thick]  ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

I think the asker used the word "*seamlessly*" in a perfect way ^^ I also see the command `buildcycle` of Asymptote just fine for this seamless domain bounded by two circles.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(5cm);
path p=unitcircle;
path q=shift(1.5,0)*p;
path r=buildcycle(p,q);
filldraw(r,green+opacity(.5),brown+1pt);
```

Is this a *seamless* infrared binocular at night ^^

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(5cm);
path p=unitcircle;
path q=shift(1.5,0)*p;
path r=buildcycle(p,q);
fill(r,lightred+opacity(.3));
shipout(bbox(5mm,Fill(black)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking Sandy G's approach of drawing a single path consisting of two arcs, but using a basic (PostScript-flavoured) `picture`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{pict2e}

\begin{document}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
\thicklines%
\begin{picture}(1.8071,1.1)
\def\twocircles{
    \circlearc{0.55}{0.55}{0.5}{45}{315}
    % cos(45) + 0.55 = 1.2571
    \circlearc{1.2571}{0.55}{0.5}{-135}{135}
    \closepath
}%
{\color{yellow!30}\twocircles\fillpath}%
{\color{orange!80}\twocircles\strokepath}%
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]